# Pass Value from one screen to another screen filter Parameter

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

Hi i am developing LightSwitch HTML client using VS 2013

need some ideas for,

I am having one browse screen for eg please refer the below,

BrowseEmployee

[image]

when i click on any row, it will lead to another screen (Not to the same entity View screen). In the another screen i am going to show with the lot of details,

ViewResourceAllocation

[image]

and in this screen i am pulling from SQL view entity, this will have ID field which is common to the previous screen (BrowseEmployee)

Now my question is,

1. If i click the ID 1 employee in the 1st screen here i need to show only the Employee ID 1 details alone.
2. Even i tried to pass the value as parameter to the filters in the second screen, nothing is working out. So it will be convenient if i pass the value as filter parameter to the other screen.

Can anyone please tell me how to sort out this issue ?

thanks!

Comment: on your view screen, does the ResourceAllocation table appear as Blue in the left panel just to make sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important bit of info first, make sure the ViewScreen is actually associated to your Engineers screen, not the **ResourceAllocation** screen, as there is a foreign key linking them together, then the information can be accessed this way. so *BrowseEngineers* will go to *ViewEngineers*

This is how I do it when there is a relationship between the tables, so on your side bar you should see "*Edit* *Query*" next to the **ResourceAllocation**. table. if its just blue under the Employee table click on it and then it will add this table to the screen, then click on the "**Edit** **Query**" button

In here there are 3 options, I will apply it to your tables from above

1. **Filter** - [WHERE] [Employee.EmployeeID] [=] [passEmployeeID]
2. **Sort** //not needed in this example
3. **Parmeters** = [Parameter] [passEmployeeID] of type [Integer]

Now when you click "*Back to ViewResourceAllocation*", under the **ResourceAllocation** table your parameter you have just created is now present. Then do the following steps

1. Drag this onto the screen and set its properties to be "*Not Visible*"
2. click "*Edit postRender Code*" and type the following code in:

> ```
> myapp.ViewEpmloyees.passEmployeeID_postRender = function (element,   contentItem) {
>       contentItem.screen.passEmployeeID=
>       contentItem.screen.Employees.EmployeeID;
>      };
> ```

We have just created a filter for the **ResourceAllocation** Table, and set is as a parameter, then now we need this to have a value, so we assign it before the screen renders as the Employee's ID you clicked on from the previous **BrowseEmployees** screen which Lightswitch passes for you.

Hopefully this will solve the problem you are having.

NOTE: make sure that you also have the EmployeeID on the screen, and if you don't want the user to see it, make it "*Not Visible*"

Answer (score 1):

to **manually pass a parameter**, repeat the steps below, and then do the additional: (and for an example ill

1. on the left hand window where it says passEmployeeID, it should now appear twice, click on the one with the small box next to it and then the properties window should display for this in the bottom right corner. In here tick the "***Is*** **Parameter**" box and for testing, unTick "***Is*** **Required**"
2. go back to your BrowseEmployees screen and click on the "*Item Tap*" on your Tile list/ table list. you will now see that is says "passEmployeeID" in here. So now the ViewEmployee screen is asking for the EmployeeID, so we must make the ID a parameter.
3. to create the Parameter, click on the Edit Query of the Employees table and follow the steps below, except before you go back, tick the "is Optional" option for the parameter (when you click on the parameter this option is displayed in the properties box in the bottom right corner.
4. Finally drag this parameter onto the screen and as you did in step one, change its properties to "**is** **Parameter**" and make sure "**is** **Required**" is false... Now if you repeat step 2, and click on the text box next to "**passEmployeeID**", the new parameter you have created on the BrowseScreen will now be one of the options, click on this and click ok.

You have now successfully passed a parameter from one screen to another, In the below example its pretty pointless however this is how it is done.

if you have any questions post a comment and ill reply when I can